# Can a pre-receive hook block a user from pushing new files/folders?

Tags: git, githooks, bitbucket-server

I am trying to write a pre-receive hook which could block a user from pushing new files and folders. I know how to block a user from pushing changes but now I want to block new files/folders. The user should be able to push updates.